# Adicionar espaços ao final do campo - python

Tags: python

tenho um arquivo *.txt no qual existe uma coluna com o código do produto e outra coluna com o valor da quantidade conforme abaixo:

```
Cód.          qtd
7513020087041;5.0

879705341017;24.0

11713777;8.0

17565097;2.0

181420;20.0

181421;20.0
```

Porém o sistema para o qual exporto este arquivo não aceita pois o campo código precisa estar formatado com 13 caracteres, e se caso não possuir os 13 caracteres ele precisa ser preenchido com espaços em branco como no exemplo abaixo:

```
7513200870410;5.0

879075341017_;24.0

11713777_____;8.0

17565097_____;2.0

181420_______;20.0

181421_______;20.0
```

Obs: Lêia-se '_' = ' ' espaços.

Comment: Para essa operação talvez seja melhor usar [AWK](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK) do que Python. Ficara algo assim em AWK `awk -F';' '{ if ($1 != "") printf "%-13s;%s\n", $1, $2; else print }' NOME_ARQUIVO
`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podes usar [`ljust`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_ljust.htm):

```
print('7513200870410'.ljust(13)) # '7513200870410'
print('181420'.ljust(13)) # '181420       '
```

Ou format (python3.x):

```
print('{:<13}'.format(7513200870410)) # '7513200870410'
print('{:<13}'.format(181420)) # '181420       '
```

Exemplo com os teus dados para gravares posteriormente num ficheiro:

```
dados = '''
    7513020087041;5.0
    879705341017;24.0
    11713777;8.0
    17565097;2.0
    181420;20.0
    181421;20.0
'''

dados_new = ''
for d in dados.split():
    cod, qtd = d.split(';')
    dados_new += '{:<13};{}\n'.format(cod, qtd)

# guardar dados_new em um novo ficheiro:
""" OUTPUT
7513020087041;5.0
879705341017 ;24.0
11713777     ;8.0
17565097     ;2.0
181420       ;20.0
181421       ;20.0
"""
```

[DEMONSTRAÇÃO](https://repl.it/repls/AzureBothRooster)

Se quiseres gravar em um ficheiro outra vez com tudo formatado podes, a seguir ao código do exemplo acima:

```
...
print('\n'.join('{};{}'.format(x,y) for x,y in dados_new), file=open('new_file.txt', 'w'))

# output:
"""
7513020087041;5.0
879705341017 ;24.0
11713777     ;8.0
17565097     ;2.0
181420       ;20.0
181421       ;20.0
"""
```

[DEMONSTRAÇÃO](https://repl.it/repls/MajorOlivedrabCougar)

Comment: Posso fazer isso com um 'for' ou ' while'?  pois o arquivo possui muitas linhas, muita mesmo...

Comment: :-)  eu ia comentar do uso do format (e no Python 3.6, as fstrings também aceitam os parâmetros usados pelo format)

Comment: Claro @CelsoLopes, vou colocar um exemplo com o teu cod

Comment: @jsbueno, eu sabia que format também dava mas tive de testar porque já não me lembrava bem da sintaxe. Obgado pelo reparo

Comment: @Miguel, eu testei e funcionou, mas quando faço no arquivo não está funcionando, veja meu código e o erro:

Comment: with open('Produtos.txt', 'a') as arq:
    arq_new = []
   for d in arq.split():
        cod, qtd = d.split(';')
        arq_new.append(('{:<13}'.format(cod), qtd))
    print(arq_new)

Comment: @CelsoLopes: https://repl.it/repls/BlandRichPiranha

Comment: @Miguel, exatamente isso, muito obrigado cara.  Agora, quando jogo para um novo arquivo ele está criando um salto de linha '\n' me deixando com um linha em branco entre um dado e outro, como removo isso?

Comment: @Miguel, consegui, valeu!! só remover o '\n' da última linha onde voce me forneceu :  print('\n'.join('{};{}'.format(x,y) for..., então ficou assim :print(''.join('{};{}'.format(x,y) for...   Muito obrigado mesmo!!!

Comment: @CelsoLopes ainda bem. Boa sorte

Comment: Graças a sua ajuda ;)

Answer (score -4):

Você pode inicialmente criar uma lista vazia para armazenar os produtos. Ao percorrer as linhas do arquivo, você cria um dicionário para armazenar os dados de cada produto e adiciona à lista. No final, você percorre a lista de produtos e imprime os dados na tela. O try - except serve para o programa não parar ao percorrer as linhas vazias. Tente deste jeito:

```
arquivo = open("<nome_do_arquivo>.txt")
produtos = []

for linha in arquivo.readlines():
    if 'Cód' not in linha:
        try:
            produto_list = linha.split(";")
            codigo = produto_list[0].ljust(13)
            valor = produto_list[1]
            produto = {"codigo": codigo, "valor": valor}
            produtos.append(produto)
        except:
            pass

for produto in produtos:
    codigo = produto["codigo"]
    valor = produto["valor"]
    print(f"{codigo};{valor}")
```

Python é minha linguagem favorita para este tipo de operação. Com apenas um arquivo de poucas linhas e um comando de terminal, a gente faz mostruosidades.

Comment: Tem muitos problemas com essa abordagem. A maneira como abriu o arquivo e não o fechou causa vazamento de memória. A leitura integral dos dados e seu espelhamento, a depender do tamanho do arquivo, pode consumir toda a memória de trabalho o que associado ao uso do tratamento inespecífico de exceções pode derrubar o Sistema Operacional ao tratar com `pass` com um `MemoryError`.  A reiteração e a forma de uso das estruturas de dados amentam muito a complexidade de tempo do algoritmo o que poderia ser resolvido em tempo linear está operando em tempo quadrático.

Comment: Sem ônus ou demérito, esse código foi gerado com BARD ou ChatGPT?

Comment: Não. Eu escrevi este programa na minha máquina e executei. Agora, quanto a fechar o arquivo depois das operações, de fato foi vacilo meu. Deveria ter fechado o programa com o comando "arquivo.close()". No meu computador não deu problema provavelmente porque o arquivo era pequeno. Por que você achou que eu recorri à Inteligência Artificial?

Comment: O que me levou a pensar que fosse IA foi a quantidade de erros no código para uma pessoa que disse que python era a linguagem preferida para a tarefa, sendo que python não é a melhor linguagem para a tarefa. Na verdade python é muito verborrágico para processamento de arquivos texto, existem linguagens muito mais eficientes para a tarefa por exemplo perl e awk que fazem essa atividade em uma linha.

Comment: Não sei programar nem em perl nem em awk. Sei poucas linguagens. Sou iniciante. Só sei mesmo Java, Python, JavaScript e PHP (Laravel) e um pouco de C e C++ e R.

Comment: Eu já precisei manipular arquivos grandes várias vezes que consegui em Python. Provavelmente, eu utilizei o comando para fechar o arquivo - aqui foi esquecimento meu. Quando quero fazer uma coisa simples e rápida que depende de programação, você acha que eu deva aprender a linguagem ideal do zero, sendo que a linguagem que eu domino já faz?

Comment: Eu estou tentando dizer que não acho que você domine a linguagem e que cometeu muitos erros no seu código de exemplo e que não achei lega você ter dito que *"...Python é minha linguagem favorita para este tipo de operação. Com apenas um arquivo de poucas linhas e um comando de terminal, a gente faz mostruosidades..."*. Veja se com um exemplo em Python você entende os problemas do seu código: https://replit.com/@Augusto-Vasques/TrivialRudeAddresses#main.py

Comment: Veja também esse comentário que anexei a pergunta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/268558/adicionar-espa%c3%a7os-ao-final-do-campo-python#comment1020629_268558